# Get Instagram login ID through API auth login

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm trying to make a check for a specific user logging into Instagram and approving an app I've created. Is this possible?

Example flow :

- User comes to my app
- User clicks login/authenticate via Instagram
- User logs in (or check is made if user is logged in via Instagram)
- User is redirected to my app's callback URI.

When the user gets back to my app I would like to be able to check which user has authenticated - is this possible? At present I'm only able to get an access token.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually solved this by using the server-side flow mentioned in the API documentation (http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) which gives me back a response including the details of the user logged in if following the extra step (code->access_code application, etc).
I also figured out what you mention above too, so both ways are good.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The information is not directly returned to you in the OAuth process, but once you have the access token you can load user information using the https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=XXXX endpoint.  That will give you data about the currently logged in user (including ID and username)